# org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, hibernate-mapping, named-query

I have a namedQuery thru which I pass 2 parameters like below,

```
ArrayList idName= new ArrayList();
     idName.add(id); --int
     idName.add(ABC); --String
```

and I pass this object to namedQuery as follows:

```
return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("findIDAndName", idName);
```

and my hbm.xml has this query,

```
  <sql-query name="findIDAndName">
      <return alias="IdNamePmt" class="com.app.Grp.model.IdNamePmt"/>
      <![CDATA[select * from PMT.CSE_NME_VW where PMT_ID=? and PMT_NAME=?]]>
    </sql-query>
```

When i run the application I get the below error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 2, actual parameters: [[7, ABC]] [select * from PMT.CSE_NME_VW where PMT_ID=? and PMT_NAME=?]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:172)
```

I have passed 2 parameters and my 'where' clause also expects 2 parameters. What is wrong?
any examples highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("findIDAndName", idName.toArray());
```

Comment: That did not help. Any examples?

Comment: The 2nd argument of `findByNamedQuery()` should be an array, not a list. Do you still get an exception? What is the error message?